# How come some of my nested routes aren't being rendered? ReactRouter4

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have a file with my routes in it:

```
const routes = (
  <App>
    <Switch>
      <Route component={Login} path="/login" />
      <Route path="/" component={SecuredRoutes} />
    </Switch>
  </App>
);
```

Inside my `SecuredRoutes` Component, I have a `Switch` Component:

```
const SecuredRoutes = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route component={Home} exact path={`/`} />
    <Route component={Other} path={`/other`} />
    <Route component={Admin} path={`/admin`} />
  </Switch>
)
```

The `Home` `Component` renders fine.  It has links on it to `Admin` and `Other`.  When I click on one of the `Link`'s, the url changes, but the `Component` doesn't render.  I can refresh the page, and then the `Component` will render.  The routes work, but only with a hard refresh.

I have also tried destructuring `match` in the `SecuredRoutes` `Component` and using `match.url` in the `path`.  That didn't help either.

Does this make sense to anyone?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try wrapping your home component that contains links to /other and /admin with `withRouter HOC`

Comment: That didn't help me.  I got the same behavior.

Comment: So I added `withRouter` higher in the tree and it now works.  [Here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/blocked-updates.md) is the document that talks about this issue.

Comment: Answer the Question, so I can accept your answer.

Comment: It would be better if you answer your own question. I just pointed you in a direction, you found out a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that because of `Redux`, the state/props don't appear to be changing, so nothing renders.  [Here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/blocked-updates.md) is a `md` that describes the issue.

I tried to wrap the lower level `Components` in `withRouter`, but they were never getting rendered, so the code was never called.  I finally wrapped my top level component with `withRouter` and now everything renders as expected.

I do not know if this causes extra renders unnecessarily.  I haven't done any profiling to see how this affects my app, but it is rendering properly.